# Apache Beam load dictionaries to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I am having trouble loading data into BiqQuery using Apache Beam. The code is making an API call, which is returning rows of what should be dictionaries (as below). My understanding is that I should then look at doing `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()` in order to make something that can be iterated over in order to pass into BQ. However whenever I try this I am getting an issue about not being able to iterate over a str, as it shouldn't be a string at this point it leads me to think that something isn't processing properly but I'm not sure what it might be. I'm not that experienced with Python so i'm unsure where to go from here.

```
{"id":"1234","source":"example","country":"Example Country","region":"Example Region","exampleKey":"example","name":"Test","code":"null","currency":"EUR","status":1},"Detail":{"id":"1234","name":"example","code":"example","currency":"EUR"},"dateDetail":{"date":"2021-04-24","itemId":"1234"},"cost":[{"Type":"1","TypeName":"example","price":0.0}]}
{"id":"1234","source":"example","country":"Example Country","region":"Example Region","exampleKey":"example","name":"Test","code":"null","currency":"EUR","status":1},"Detail":{"id":"1234","name":"example","code":"example","currency":"EUR"},"dateDetail":{"date":"2021-04-24","itemId":"5678"},"cost":[{"Type":"1","TypeName":"example","price":0.0}]}
```

The pipline code is as follows:

```
           class callAPI(beam.DoFn):
                def __init__(self, input_header):
                    self.headers = input_header
                   # self.remote_url = input_uri
            
                def process(self, input_uri):
                    try:
                        res = requests.get(input_uri, headers=self.headers) 
                        res.raise_for_status()
                    except HTTPError as message:
                        logging.error(message)
                        return

                    
                    data = json.loads(json.dumps(res.text))

                    yield data 
      
    def run():
        with beam.Pipeline() as p:
           data = ( p 
                            | beam.Create([REMOTE_URI])
                            | 'Call API ' >> beam.ParDo(callAPI(HEADER)) 
                            | 'Write to BQ ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                              table = table_name1,
                              schema = table_schema,
                              method="STREAMING_INSERTS",
                              create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED  ,
                              write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND )
                            )
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

error:

```
   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items' [while running 'Write to BQ /_StreamToBigQuery/StreamInsertRows/ParDo(BigQueryWriteFn)']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a closer look at the structure I was getting in as I realised I needed the data to be in a list before I could process it. I've added the following and this allows me to process the data to load into BigQuery.

```
class convertJson(beam.DoFn):

    def process (self, res):

        data_list = []
        for i in res.splitlines(): 
          data_list.append(i)
       

        data = []
        for i in data_list:
          data.append(json.loads(i))


        yield data
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following snippet to split JSON:-

```
class Transaction(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        result = json.loads(element)
        
        data_id =  result['id']
        data_source = result['source']
        data_country =  result['country']
        data_region = result['region']
        data_exampleKey =  result['exampleKey']
        data_name = result['name']
        data_code =  result['code']
        data_currency = result['currency']
        data_status = result['status']
        
        return [{"id": data_id,"source": data_source,"country": data_country,"region": data_region, "exampleKey": data_exampleKey, "name": data_name, "code": data_code, "currency": data_currency, "status": data_status}]
```

Comment: Due to the structure of the data json.loads() wasn't working, as it was just processing everything as one huge string. I've worked out how to process it and I'll post it below.

Comment: Just try to test parsing JSON data through normal Python code. As it looks like your input data has some additional characters and it is breaking while parsing through above given function. Above code is a working code and i have using it in my project to parse JSON records.

Comment: On further investigation I found that there was a rogue new line at the end of the data which I just kept missing. I've got my code working, by using .split() but also by writing to and reading from a GCS bucket (not sure why i can't get it working without doing that though).

Comment: Good to here that your code is working now, because of extra character it was not working before. On Reading and writing data from GCS should work provide if you have correct Service account roles. Verify roles of service account which is been used to execute Dataflow code.